# SQL - Select statement inside case

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I want to select particular columns from a table when some field in other table is not null.

In other words, I have two tables, they have common fields so when field named "salesordrkey" in table number 1 is not null then I need to get the common fields from table number 2 otherwise get the common fields from table number 1

Here's what I am trying to do

```
Select slsordr.salesordrkey,
       whissue.warehissuekey, 
       issuppk.issueprodpackkey,
       (Case When  whissue.salesordrkey Is Not Null Then
           (Select slsordr.busipartnerkey,
                   slsordr.contractkey,
                   slsordr.salesmankey,
                   slsordr.customerkey)
        Else
           (Select whissue.busipartnerkey,
                   whissue.contractkey,
                   whissue.salesmankey,
                   slsordr.customerkey)
        End)
 From warehissues whissue 
     Inner Join issueprodpacks issuppk on whissue.warehissuekey = issuppk.warehissuekey
     Left Join slssalesordrs slsordr on whissue.salesordrkey = slsordr.salesordrkey 
 Where
      whissue.partitionkey = @prtnkey and 
      issuppk.prodpackkey = @prodpackkey
```

but this didn't work .. is there any other way to achieve that?

Comment: You might be better off sharing the table structures as well with the question. Given the content in the question, have you considered using any other join and where conditions?

Comment: First of all, when you state a SELECT, you have to state where to select FROM. Second, you can select 4 columns into one, you have to do case for each one. And last, you already joined the table, so the information from the second table is accessible, you dont have to select anything again, just use the information you got.

Comment: A case expression returns a simple value, you try to return 4 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that your logic is backwards.  Instead of:

```
case when  whissue.salesordrkey is not null . . .
```

I think you intend:

```
case when  slsordr.salesordrkey is not null
```

The first doesn't check to see if the `left join` is working.

So, you can use `coalesce()`:

```
select slsordr.salesordrkey, whissue.warehissuekey, issuppk.issueprodpackkey,
       coalesce(slsordr.busipartnerkey, whissue.busipartnerkey) as busipartnerkey,
       coalesce(slsordr.contractkey, whissue.contractkey) as contractkey,
       coalesce(slsordr.salesmankey, whissue.salesmankey),
       coalesce(slsordr.customerkey, whissue.customerkey)
from warehissues whissue inner join
     issueprodpacks issuppk
     on whissue.warehissuekey = issuppk.warehissuekey left join 
     slssalesordrs slsordr
     on whissue.salesordrkey = slsordr.salesordrkey
where whissue.partitionkey = @prtnkey and 
      issuppk.prodpackkey = @prodpackkey
```

I should note that this is not 100% exactly the same logic.  It is possible that some records with a match have `NULL` values in the `slsordr` table.  Using `coalesce()` would then bring in the values from the other table, even though there is a match.  However, this is often the logic.

Otherwise, you need to use multiple `case` statements:

```
       (case when slsorderkey is not null then slsordr.busipartnerkey
             else whissue.busipartnerkey
        end) as busipartnerkey,
```

`case` is an expression.  It returns only one value, not multiple values.

Comment: That will do the trick but I think you should also include an explanation since he have more than 1 mistake in his code, and tell him what he did wrong.

Comment: No, I didn't intend that, as salesordrkey  is a primary key in the slsordr table. 
Thank you for your answer, it did help me.